# GWT - how to get method A of service A from method B of Service B?

Tags: gwt, servlets, rpc, vs-web-application-project, web-container

I have GWT projects as .war A and .war B... each .war's servlet contains methods like a

- .war A - String methodA(){return "this is method A of .war A";}
- .war B - String methodB(){return (?).methodA(); }

The thing is... I'd like to get methodA value from methodB. So my question is...
Is it possible to do that? And how to do that according to GWT?

Any useful comment is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you need to include all modules (like A) in module B in the gwt config file.

After that, use a Generator to dynamically create a method which return the value of method A by calling the good module

Comment: I've never seen any tutorial of that. Have you got one?

Comment: http://vinaytech.wordpress.com/2008/10/01/gwt-generator-why-do-at-runtime-what-you-can-do-at-compile-time/

Comment: I am going to try it and report my results :)